# Python convert epoch time to day of the week

Tags: python, date, python-2.7, datetime, time

How can I do this in Python? I just want the day of the week to be returned.

```
>>> convert_epoch_time_to_day_of_the_week(epoch_time_in_miliseconds)
>>> 'Tuesday'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
ep =  1412673904406

from datetime import datetime

print datetime.fromtimestamp(ep/1000).strftime("%A")
Tuesday


def ep_to_day(ep):
    return datetime.fromtimestamp(ep/1000).strftime("%A")
```

Comment: Why is the epoch divided by 1000?

Answer (score 5):

```
import time

epoch = 1496482466
day = time.strftime('%A', time.localtime(epoch))
print day

>>> Saturday
```

Comment: Nice first post! I would suggest adding an explanation to improve the answer.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 3):

```
from datetime import date

def convert_epoch_time_to_day_of_the_week(epoch_time_in_miliseconds):
    d = date.fromtimestamp(epoch_time_in_miliseconds / 1000)
    return d.strftime('%A')
```

Tested, returned Tuesday.

Comment: I don't think there are many possible variations; also, there used to be an Ajax notification on SO if answers were posted while you were writing, but this time around I saw none... Is that thing still working?

Comment: not sure but you need to convert from millesecs to get it to work

Answer (score 2):

If you have milliseconds, you can use the [`time`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html) module:

```
import time
time.strftime("%A", time.gmtime(epoch/1000))
```

It returns:

```
'Tuesday'
```

Note we use `%A` as described in [strftime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime):

> **time.strftime**(format[, t])
>
> **%A**  Locale’s full weekday name.

---

As a function, let's convert the miliseconds to seconds:

```
import time

def convert_epoch_time_to_day_of_the_week(epoch_milliseconds):
    epoch = epoch_milliseconds / 1000
    return time.strftime("%A", time.gmtime(epoch))
```

Testing...

Today is:

```
$ date +"%s000"
1412674656000
```

Let's try another date:

```
$ date -d"7 Jan 1993" +"%s000"
726361200000
```

And we run the function with these values:

```
>>> convert_epoch_time_to_day_of_the_week(1412674656000)
'Tuesday'
>>> convert_epoch_time_to_day_of_the_week(726361200000)
'Wednesday'
```

Comment: `time.gmtime()` returns UTC time. `time.strftime()` works with local time. You probably want `time.localtime(ts)` here.